# Solution to inequality $x \leq c_1 + c_2 x^{\alpha}$?

Tags: inequality

Suppose that $c_1, c_2 > 0$. I am interested in the positive solutions to the inequality
$$
x \leq c_1 + c_2 x^{\alpha},
$$
where $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. To give an example, say $\alpha = 1/2$, Then this inequality is
$$
x \leq c_1 + c_2 \sqrt{x},
$$
which has a solution via the quadratic formula in the variable $z = \sqrt{x}$, and it will result in a solution set, over the positive reals,
$$
0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{4}\Big(\sqrt{c_2^2 + 4c_1} + c_2\Big)^2.
$$
Is there an analogous simple formula for general $\alpha \in (0, 1)$?

Comment: Only an example: For rational $\alpha=\frac{m}{n}$ ($m,n\in\mathbb{N}_+$), the equation can be transformed into a polynomial equation of degree $\max(m,n)$. If $m,n\le 4$, all these equations are solvable by radicals by the usual solution formulas for algebraic equations up to degree 4.

Answer (score 0):

Even with simple exponents and coefficients, solving the inequality would involve solving equations that don't have closed form solutions. For example, solving $x \le 1 + x^{1/5}$ is equivalent to solve the quintic equation $y^5 = 1+y$, which  [is not solvable by radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem). In general, you would have to leave the answer in an implicit form or recur to numeric methods if you have concrete values for $c_1$, $c_2$ and $\alpha$.